# Is it good to have / after website URL for SEO?

Tags: seo, url, url-rewriting, canonical-url

Which one of the following links is the correct and SEO friendly URL?
`http://example.com/software/view/35531716?download=WhatsApp-2.12.258.apk/` (with / at the end) or
`http://example.com/software/view/35531716?download=WhatsApp-2.12.258.apk` (without / at the end)?

Comment: Adding the / slash at the end invalidates the request- the webserver will now take your *35531716?download=WhatsApp-2.12.258.apk* and look for a directory of that name.

Comment: It can be a bit of a redirect trickery. It could also be a directory. It could be both. I have never seen this before that I recall. Someone here should know something.

Comment: Upon thinking about it, I do not think that one over the other would be better or much better from an search performance perspective. They are mostly the same. I do believe that semantics against a directory versus a file name is slightly more advantageous, however, I am not sure if so, by how much.

Comment: @closetnoc So what do you suggest? Should I add / at the end of URL or not?

Comment: I would not personally bother, but that is just me. If you want to and know how to and can create a canonical tag pointing to just one, then **Why Not?** If you want to, I cannot see how it will hurt! Just remember the canonical tag so that Google does not see it as duplicate content.

Comment: @closetnoc Adding a slash at the end of the URL in the OP's example won't make the server look for a directory - the slash in this case is at the end of the _query string_, not the URL-path.

Comment: @Macraze `/video/list/5534942` also returns the same page (which I suspect is the canonical URL). The query string does not seem to be required in this case - this might just serve to make it more human readable.

Comment: @w3d That has not been my experience with query strings and Apache at least... for example, I found that a query string ending with .pl (domain name) will try and run a perl script. Adding a slash should cause Apache to look for a directory without some kind of intervention. This could have different behaviors on other web servers- in that you have a good point. The OP may see different behaviors on different web servers.

Comment: @w3d This may have to do with mod_dir being enabled or not or how it is configured- not sure. It could be a behavior that is easily turned on and off. I just know that in all 4 Apache installs I have here, adding a trailing slash will cause Apache to look for a directory.